# PHP Zend Engine Extension and static methods

Tags: php, c, php-extension, php-internals

On writing an extension for php (5.3) i want to access the `zend_class_entry` pointer on a static method.

On non static methods i can use the `getThis()` macro and within `Z_OBJCE_P` macro like this:

```
zend_class_entry ce* = Z_OBJCE_P(getThis());
```

Now the problem:
on static methods the `getThis()` macro returns a `null` pointer, so i can not use the `Z_OBJCE_P` macro.

Has anyone a solution for me to access the `zend_class_entry` from a static method??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is really interesting: 
on static methods you can access the scope like this

```
zend_class_entry* ce = 0L;
if (EG(called_scope)) {
    ce = EG(called_scope);
} else if (!EG(scope))  {
    ce = EG(scope);
}
```

the EG Macro access a lot of global and context specific variables, also the calling scope, the calling class of the static method.

Comment: Note the called scope is not the same as the (calling) scope, the first is related to LSB, the second is probably what you want.