# Is void *p = 0L valid?

Tags: c

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514202/php-zend-engine-extension-and-static-methods/4519501#4519501), [`sassman`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551760/sassman) initializes a pointer with:

```
zend_class_entry* ce = 0L;
```

My question is – is this valid? I would say it isn't, to initialize the variable with a null pointer either an unadorned (and possibly casted to 
 `void *`) `0` constant, or some macro that evaluates to that such as `NULL` should be used.

However, I can't find definitive language in the standard that supports this interpretation. All it says is:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
>   void *, is called a *null pointer constant*.

Comment: NULL is 0x0 which is equal to 0L... so I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: @JustSid:  In C, `NULL` is defined as `(void*)0` or something to that effect.

Comment: @JustSid: What exactly do you mean by "0x0 equal to 0L" here? "Equal"? Compare equal? But `0x0` also compares equal to `0.0`, but `0.0` cannot be used as a null-pointer constant.

Comment: 0L is an integer, written as hexadecimal its 0x0 which can be used as pointer adress. NULL = 0x0 = 0L. But! 0.0f is floating point and thus different from integers like 0L. Thats what makes 0x0 equal to 0L but unequal to 0.0f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0L` is an integral constant expression with the value of zero.  When used as a pointer, such a constant expression is a null pointer constant.  That's exactly what the sentence you cite says (C99 6.3.2.3/3):

> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant.

This is followed immediately by a statement that a null pointer constant can be converted to a null pointer:

> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Why do you think that `0` is not usable as a null pointer constant?

Comment: Because the constant `0L` is not exactly the same as the constant `0`, as the first as type long, and the standard only mentions `0`.

Comment: @Artefacto:  It's still "an integral constant expression with the value `0`."  `0` and `0L` may have different types but they have the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely *any* integral constant expression with zero value will be treated by the compiler as a null-pointer constant. `0L` is a perfectly valid null-pointer constant, so the code is absolutely valid.

Answer (score -3):

You can set all builtin POD types to the literal constant 0 without casting.

Comment: And you cannot set structs and unions to `0`. `{0}` is the universal zero-initializer for **all** types in C, but for assignment you'll need a C99 compound literal still (`(type){0}`).

Comment: structs and unions are not PODs.  So my original statement is correct.  By POD type I mean anything that can be represented by a single machine register (int, float, enum etc).